# wordpress media upload given An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later

Tags: uploads, media-library

i am using wordpress 4.8.3 . my website was working fine but when i moved it to another server , i saw some images of my posts are missing and when i am trying to reupload these images i faced another error **

```
An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.
```

Another wonder is that images is uploading the uploads folder but it not showing in media library and also media library not displaying any image. When i went to network tab and try to upload an images it returns me true response.

```
{success: true,…}
data
:
[{id: 72314, title: "Interactive meetings work best for their business", filename: "banner-1.jpg",…},…]
0
:
{id: 72314, title: "Interactive meetings work best for their business", filename: "banner-1.jpg",…}
1
:
{id: 72313, title: "aza", filename: "aza.png",…}
2
:
{id: 72310, title: "Capture", filename: "Capture.png",…}
3
:
{id: 72307, title: "15243100945408420050134584705011",…}
4
:
{id: 72306, title: "Interactive meetings work best for their business", filename: "banner.jpg",…}
5
:
{id: 72304, title: "123", filename: "123-1.png",…}
6
:
{id: 72301, title: "4", filename: "4.jpg",…}
7
:
{id: 72299, title: "5", filename: "5-8.jpg",…}
8
:
{id: 72297, title: "adamosmpeisfhgj", filename: "adamosmpeisfhgj-1.jpg",…}
9
:
{id: 72295, title: "5", filename: "5-7.jpg",…}
10
:
{id: 72292, title: "123", filename: "123.png",…}
11
:
{id: 72291, title: "5", filename: "5-6.jpg",…}
12
:
{id: 72289, title: "5", filename: "5-5.jpg",…}
13
:
{id: 72288, title: "5", filename: "5-4.jpg",…}
14
:
{id: 72287, title: "5", filename: "5-3.jpg",…}
15
:
{id: 72285, title: "5", filename: "5-2.jpg",…}
16
:
{id: 72284, title: "5", filename: "5-1.jpg",…}
17
:
{id: 72283, title: "5", filename: "5.jpg",…}
18
:
{id: 72282, title: "Hydrangeas", filename: "Hydrangeas.jpg",…}
19
:
{id: 72281, title: "Chrysanthemum", filename: "Chrysanthemum-1.jpg",…}
20
:
{id: 72280, title: "Chrysanthemum", filename: "Chrysanthemum.jpg",…}
21
:
{id: 72277, title: "logo cy properties", filename: "logo-cy-properties.png",…}
22
:
{id: 72276, title: "logo cy properties", filename: "logo-cy-properties-3.png",…}
23
:
{id: 72275, title: "logo cy properties", filename: "logo-cy-properties-2.png",…}
24
:
{id: 72274, title: "logo cy properties", filename: "logo-cy-properties-1.png",…}
25
:
{id: 72272, title: "logo cy properties", filename: "logo-cy-properties.png",…}
26
:
{id: 72271, title: "A4_1-item", filename: "A4_1-item.png",…}
27
:
{id: 72266, title: "agiatri", filename: "agiatri-1.jpg",…}
28
:
{id: 72257, title: "14184445_846307228839982_657568723936121234_n",…}
29
:
{id: 72256, title: "14184445_846307228839982_657568723936121234_n",…}
30
:
{id: 72255, title: "KRITIKOS", filename: "KRITIKOS-1.jpg",…}
31
:
{id: 72253, title: "KRITIKOS", filename: "KRITIKOS.jpg",…}
32
:
{id: 72251, title: "αυτο", filename: "αυτο.jpg",…}
33
:
{id: 72248, title: "VROXES", filename: "VROXES-1.jpg",…}
34
:
{id: 72247, title: "VROXES", filename: "VROXES.jpg",…}
35
:
{id: 72243, title: "mo", filename: "mo.jpg",…}
36
:
{id: 72241, title: "arx", filename: "arx.jpg",…}
37
:
{id: 72236, title: "parko", filename: "parko.jpg",…}
38
:
{id: 72232, title: "ze", filename: "ze-7.jpg",…}
39
:
{id: 72231, title: "ze", filename: "ze-6.jpg",…}
success
:
true
```

Comment: Try checking the permissions for the uploads folder and its subfolders. Should be 755 or 744 for some servers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it has solve . I deactivated the current theme and enable default twenty sixteen theme and re-enable my theme, it working